# Offline Mobile web app is not working when I use apple-web-app-capable

Tags: html, offlineapps

Im using  meta tag to open the offline app in standalone when user comes from the home screen icon then its showing error "Cannot open app"(requires internet connection). when i'm not using the above meta tag everything works fine but in the safari not in standalone.

can anyone suggest some fix to handle this and run offline in standalone?